# Make guest name visible to host

Tags: networking, dns, vmware-player

I have Ubuntu running in VMware Player.  I am able to access an Apache instance on this VM by using the IP address but not by machine name.

How do I make the name of the VM visible to the host?  How do I add the machine name to my DNS?  I am running within a Windows network.

Comment: Why the close vote? If we can discuss editors, furniture and interviews then why can't we discuss networking? FYI, I'm trying to set up SVN on the VM and access that from the host. Does that make it "programming related" enough?

Comment: I agree. I don't know why we shouldn't talk about these topics here on SO as well. Networking for many programmers is an important part of what they have to deal with.

Comment: @martin it's a slippery slope, but definitely not programming related.

Comment: @Roger Pate: I believe the title: "Make VM Machine name..." would make it more obvious that we're talking about VMs here. Also, this is more Google friendly than "guest" to those who are searching for VM related quries.

Comment: @Vulcan: I was avoiding "Virtual Machine Machine" (from "VM Machine"), but if there's a tweak you'd like to apply, feel free.

Answer (score 1):

Put it in either DNS or in `/etc/hosts`.

EDIT: If the host is a Windows machine, put it in `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\host`.

Both are bascially the same syntax, which is

```
IP hostname1 hostname2 hostname3 ...
```

e.g.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.mydomain.tld
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use mDNS, giving your name an automacic .local domain.

```
apt-get install avahi
```

or see: http://avahi.org/

Answer (score 0):

If the host is Windows:
Go to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\ open file "hosts" and add a line:

```
IP Address Hostname
```

example:

```
192.168.1.5 ubuntu
```

If the host is Linux

```
sudo vi /etc/hosts
```

Then the same.